# Issue with Software Updater installing new kernel

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, updates

I woul like to know if anyone could help me with a software updater/apt-upgrade issue (or not).

When I run the software updater, it prompts the updates for the kernel 3.19.0-42.48, but when I click on install now, it loads "something" and closes automatically, without any advise.

When I run apt-get upgrade, it shows me the available update, I accept them but kernel is not downloaded.

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the following:

1. `sudo apt-get update` to update repositories and package information
2. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to update packages and their dependencies

This should update your kernel as well.